# Failed to resolve: appcompat-v7 android studio 3.2.1

Tags: android, android-appcompat, buildbox

I exported my Build box project and opened it on Android studio. But Unable to Build it.I'm getting this error.

> Failed to resolve: appcompat-v7

Gradle file

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "27.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.test.test1"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 26
        multiDexEnabled true

        ndk {
            moduleName "player_shared"
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }

    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:+'
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    // More deps here //
}
```

anyone know how to fix this ?

Comment: Where's your `repositories` block? Do you have `google()` in it?

Comment: how to find repositories block ?

Comment: You need to show all the implementations.

Comment: I think it is this one. Yes It has google.

Comment: buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this in dependencies:

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
```

Add this in project gradle

```
allprojects {
  repositories {
  jcenter()
  maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
  google()
  }
}
```

Comment: I have to wait 5 minutes to mark it as the correct answer. thanks again :)